# Start thread with virtual member function C++

Tags: c++, pthreads

I have Base class & 2 other classes inherited from the Base class. I would like to create a thread that can run override function in Derived_* class. Which version of the function can be selected. Compile error when I create thread as in the sample code. What should I do?

Updated: As pointed in the comments, I cannot pass unique_ptr to the std::thread constructor. Using std::move or std::async both work. Thank for helping me!

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class Base{
public:
    virtual void print(const std::vector<int> &vec);
};

void Base::print(const std::vector<int> &vec){
    std::cout << "run Base::print" << std::endl;
}

class Derived_1: public Base{
public:    
    virtual void print(const std::vector<int> &vec) override;
};

void Derived_1::print(const std::vector<int> &vec){
    std::cout << "run Derived_1::print" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < (vec.size()); i++){
        std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

class Derived_2: public Base{
public:    
    virtual void print(const std::vector<int> &vec) override;
};

void Derived_2::print(const std::vector<int> &vec){
    std::cout << "run Derived_2::print" << std::endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < (vec.size()); i++){
        std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    int classType = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<Base> base;
    std::vector<int> vec{0, 1, 2};

    if(classType){
        base = std::make_unique<Derived_1>();
    }else{
        base = std::make_unique<Derived_2>();
    }

    std::thread th(&Base::print, base, std::ref(vec));
    th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you create the thread, try to change `base` argument to `base.get()`. Keep in mind this can be problematic - `std::unique_ptr<Base> base` must outlive the thread using the pointer. In this case it is OK since the thread is joined before `base` goes out of scope.

Comment: I would use a lambda and std::async to run the print asynchronously `auto std::future<void> future = std::async(std::launch::async,[&]{ base->print(); }); future.get();`
When passing pointers to threads I usually tend to use share_ptr, so the lifetime of the object is extended automatically with the lifetime matching the longest living thread.

Comment: You cannot pass a `unique_ptr`  to the std::thread constructor because it is not copyable. `std::thread th(&Base::print, std::move(base), std::ref(vec));` works.

Answer (score 0):

`base` is object of `std::unique_ptr<Base>`, you need to pass Object of `Base`.
If you pass (`*base`), it will invoke method of Base class. `base.get()` does the job and invokes appropriate method of derived class by passing derived object ptr.

--
this also works:

```
std::future<void> f1 = std::async(std::launch::async,[&]{base->print(std::ref(vec));});
f1.get();
```

`base->print` invokes appropriate method of derived class.